# Does Cassandra log query attempts that are part of a retry policy?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, gocql

For example, would these attempts be recorded as part of a trace session in system_traces.sessions or system_traces.events?

Edit: The driver I'm using is called [gocql](https://github.com/gocql/gocql)

Comment: Can you mention which driver version you are using, there are logging retry policies which will help.

Comment: Thanks for asking, Andrew. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java driver, there is a logging retry policy which can act as a parent policy for another retry policy - it should log the decision of retrying.

In the gocql driver though looking at the query executor, I cannot see an explicit log regardless of retry - only one of the retry mechanisms appears to have logging,  the DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy. If debug is set it will log the downgrade.